# Losing data and DIGITS configuration in AWS-EC2 after stopping instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, deep-learning, classification, nvidia-digits

I started to use AWS EC2 for deep learning and I'm going to use NVIDIA DIGITS. I already got a g3.4xlarge instance with 50G storage with I defined during creating instance process. Now my question is that if I upload my image's folder which is about 6GB and configure all DIGITS installation. Am I going to lose all the data and configuration after stopping my instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you won't, EBS backed data will persist even after stopping, g3.4xlarge comes with EBS backed. Data will be lost only when store it in instance storage.

Comment: Sorry to ask again I just want to make sure since I spend one day to upload my Data to AWS. Now my Data is in /home/ubuntu directory is it still safe there :S

Comment: yeah as long as it is ebs backed instance, your data will be safe.